# Is there a way to remove text formatting when copy and pasting text into Activity details section?

Tags: activity

Some information that I add into Civi to record activities may be copied and pasted form a word document, an email etc. This looks fine on the activity when reading it on Civi, however when pulling reports as a cvc file the text is littered with jargon (something like: $n&*) where ever a bit of punctuation was. I know that it reads easier (without the jargon) if for each entry the user removes the formatting, however I wondered if there was a way to make this the default.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean unicode characters like the fancy quotation marks? For CiviReports, unicode output for export to CSV was fixed in 5.22 in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16117. What version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

There are online tools available that allow you to remove unwanted tags such as this one: https://www.seabreezecomputers.com/htmlstripper/

They may not be perfect but much better than merely pasting it or simply using "ctrl + shift + v" to paste which removes all formatting (sometimes you want to keep some parts of the formatting).